# Rally.environment.getContext().getWorkspace() is null

Tags: javascript, rally

Let me start off by saying I am new to Rally and its SDK. I have successfully ran some code that I copied from the documentation by posting it directly into a custom app in Rally but when I try to view the `App-debug.html` file I get the following error in my JavaScript debug console:

```
Rally.environment.getContext().getWorkspace() is null
```

Not knowing too much about the inner workings of the Rally SDK I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I wasn't able to find any help online and the rep from Rally didn't seem to have a definitive answer either. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an issue with the preview version of the AppSDK that happens when you do not have a default project and workspace setup on your user. If you were inside the Rally application those functions would have returned the workspace and project that were shown in the upper left hand corner of the application. Since your App is not hosted inside the Rally application it uses your default project and workspace as a backup for your current settings.

The easiest fix right now is to set a default username and password as described in the help [system](http://www.rallydev.com/help/set-your-profile).

Good luck with your first App!